# How to check if string contains another string - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, string, cpu-word

I'am working with URLs and I'm try to checkif an url has the words I am looking for

I'm using this

```
$alreadySaved = 'storage.googleapis';
   $contains = Str::contains($alreadySaved, $imageUrl);

   if ($contains == false) {
```

but the result of $contains is false EVER

for example

[image]

that $imageUrl has storage.googleapis word

how can I solve it?

I need to obtain if the string has "storage.googleapis" and return true

Comment: Swap the variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is switch `$alreadySaved` and `$imageUrl`. Laravel's `Str::contains` method takes the string you're searching through first and the substring second.

Like this:

```
$contains = Str::contains($imageUrl, $alreadySaved);
```

Comment: thanks :) I don't know why I did it the other way around. I'm learning, thanks

Comment: When in doubt, [check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-contains) :)